blacklistd on freebsd not consistently blocking on ssh timeout
Roughly every minute, I'm getting the following in my log:
sshd[####]: fatal: Timeout before authentication for 118.26.194.190

There are many hundreds, this has been happening for hours.
# grep 118.26.194.190 /var/log/console.log | wc
238    4284   32368

So I'm looking at 'blacklistd' to see why it's not working.
# blacklistctl dump -a | grep 118.26.194.190
118.26.194.190/32:22   OK      3/3     2024/04/01 16:09:20
# ipfw table port22 list
118.26.194.190/32 0

In the time I've been typing this, it finally figured it out. Just a few minutes ago this IP was NOT in the 'ipfw' output, and the blacklistctl line showed "2/3". Regardless, it obviously wasn't working as there should only be 3 attempts before 'ipfw' blocking occurs, clearly that didn't happen. (There are a few other entries in table 'port22', and many other entries in 'port25' and 'port587' so things are working.) When I do a 'grep' for same IP address in the log, all the entries are the same timeout as above.
Thoughts anyone?

This is way to broad. Too many open questions with too little config info. I would advice to narrow the question scope and provide relevant config. Currently you are only talking about what you see in the logs. This format is not well suited for a lot of back and forth. Remember there is are chat rooms available (here on this site) as well which could help narrow your scope.
